# How can I pass the TKinter button/label that triggered a bind to a function which that bind calls?

Tags: python, tkinter

I hope someone can help with this. I'm new to coding and wanted to try doing some GUI stuff in Python with TKinter. In one of my projects, I want any button that the mouse hovers over to change it's background color. However I don't want to define a function for every single button. Here is an example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Example")
root.configure(bg="black")

def on_enter(e, button):
    #button = Button that triggered the bind
    button.configure(bg="red")

def on_leave(e, button):
    #button = Button that triggered the bind
    button.configure(bg="black")

button1 = Button(root, text="Button1", width=10, height=10, bg="black", fg="white")
button2 = Button(root, text="Button2", width=10, height=10, bg="black", fg="white")
button3 = Button(root, text="Button3", width=10, height=10, bg="black", fg="white")
button4 = Button(root, text="Button4", width=10, height=10, bg="black", fg="white")

button1.grid(column=0, row=0)
button2.grid(column=0, row=1)
button3.grid(column=1, row=0)
button4.grid(column=1, row=1)

#How can I give the button that triggered the bind as an argument to the functions on_enter/on_leave?
root.bind_all("<Enter>", lambda e, button: on_enter(e, button))
root.bind_all("<Leave>", lambda e, button: on_leave(e, button))

#root.bind_class("Button", "<Enter>", lambda e, button: on_enter(e, button))
#root.bind_class("Button", "<Leave>", lambda e, button: on_leave(e, button))


root.mainloop()
```

Now of course I could go and make a function for every button to change it's background color when the bind for that specific button calls that function. But is there a way to pass the button that triggered the bind to the function that the bind calls ?

My example works, if I explicitly put the button I want to change in the bind like this:

```
root.bind_all("<Enter>", lambda e, button = button1: on_enter(e, button))
root.bind_all("<Leave>", lambda e, button = button1: on_leave(e, button))
```

But I thought there must be a more elegant way to fix this other than make a bind/function for every single button which gets really annyoing when I have a program with more than only 4 buttons.

I hope someone has any advice :)

Comment: Isn't it the `button` argument in your lambda? Why would you need to define a function for every button?

Comment: @Barmar Yes the argument is in there, but its empty. Unless I specify by hand which button it should pass as an argument. Yes, that would only require one function but in turn a bind for every button. I basically just want a way to pass the button that triggered the bind_all to the function that bind_all calls (on_enter for example). That way I only have to define one function and one bind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you bind an event to a function, that function will be called with an object representing the event. This object has an attribute `widget` which is the widget that received the event.  You don't need to do anything else to get the widget.

```
def on_enter(event):
    event.widget.configure(bg="red")

root.bind_all("<Enter>", on_enter)
```